# AngularJS get parsed HTML

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In the below code, I am having a template and based on the `IsEdit` flag the corresponding view will be rendered. From here, Is there a way to get the angular parsed HTML which is only visible to the view.

e.g.

If `IsEdit = false`, then I want the rendered HTML as

```
<div>
   View Mode
</div>
```

or even

```
<div ng-show="!IsEdit">
   View Mode
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.IsEdit = false;

  $scope.GetTemplate = function () {
    console.log($("#Template").html());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="Template" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-show="IsEdit">
  Edit Mode
</div>
<div ng-show="!IsEdit">
  View Mode
</div>

<button ng-click="GetTemplate()">Get HTML</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, we use `ng-if` to completely removed it in the DOM.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.IsEdit = false;

  $scope.GetTemplate = function () {
    angular.element('#Template').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;}).remove(); // <--- to remove comments
    console.log(angular.element('#Template').html());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="Template" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-if="IsEdit">
  Edit Mode
</div>
<div ng-if="!IsEdit">
  View Mode
</div>

<button ng-click="GetTemplate()">Get HTML</button>
</div>
```